# How to ship library for Android

Tags: android, jar, apk, android-library

I want to develop a library for Android. In what form can I ship it?  jar, apk or something else? How should I do it so that other developers can use my library in their application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your library is pure Java code, a JAR is fine, perhaps ZIPped with documentation, etc.

If you need resources or other Android-specific non-Java stuff, you should look at using an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject). That is best shipped as source code, though there are tricks for packaging it up in (mostly) binary form. And the new Gradle-based build system under development should make it easier to create library projects that ship in binary (non-source) form.

Answer (score 1):

As a regular jar. Your library classes will be converted to the Dalvik VM bytecode along with a concrete application.

Answer (score 1):

I would just toss your code up on [link text](http://github.com) and allow users to download the code or fork it from there. I've seen quite a few Android libraries on GitHub.